# mov ax, bx vs. mov ax, [bx]

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

What is the difference between the following two lines?

```
mov ax, bx
mov ax, [bx]
```

If `bx` contains the value 100h and the value at memory address 100h is 23, does the second one copy 23 to `ax`?

Also, what is the difference between the two following lines?

```
mov ax, 102h ; moves value of 102h into register ax
mov ax, [102h] ; Actual address is DS:0 + 102h
```

Comment: I think the comments after the latter two lines, explain what's happening. The same applies to the first lines too, so your thoughts are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The operand between the brackets is treated as an address and the value at that memory address if fetched.