# how can i put value from memory to eax register in masm32

Tags: assembly, masm32

so i try to do "encryption" code using the xor command

this is my code

```
.486
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap :none ;case sensitive

;;_____MASM MACROS___
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

;;_____DATA____
.data
msg DB "I LIKE ASSEMLY$",0H
my_xor db 0101010101010101b

;;_____CODE____
.code
_start:

encript_lbl:

mov ax,[word msg]
xor ax,[my_xor]
mov [msg],ax
jmp print_lbl

decript_lbl:
mov ax,[msg]
xor ax,[my_xor]
mov [msg],ax


print_lbl:
mov dx,offset msg
mov ah,9h
int 21h
mov ah,2 ;new line
mov dl,10
int 21h
mov dl,13
int 21h
jmp decript_lbl





end _start
```

when i try to compile it in masm32 i get bunch of errors

```
lines 23,24,28,29,30 invalid instruction operand (a2070)
line 22 missing operator in expration (a2206)
line 34 (a2022) instruction operand must be in the same size
line 14 (a2071) initializer magnitude to large for spesofied
```

now i tried to do a lot of stuff to fix this but when i succeed to fix 1 problem i get a new one...

so this program shuld take the string "i like assembly$" encrypt this string by xor opernd of 0101010101010101  and then print the encrypted string 
and then decrypt the string again by using the xor of my_xor db 0101010101010101
and print the decrypted string

any one know how to solve this problems?

thank you guys 
mike

Comment: `xor ax,[my_xor]`: `my_xor` is declared as a single byte. `ax` is a 16-bit register (i.e. 2 bytes). `mov ax,[word msg]`: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here(?). What's `word` supposed to do?

Comment: Also, you seem to be creating a Win32 application. So those `int 21h` functions aren't going to work (those are for DOS). And why does the title mention `eax` when your code never directly uses `eax`?

Comment: So i need to decleare my_xoras dw?

Comment: and eax is my mistake sorry abaut this , i put [word msg] becoas i was thinking that the problem is that msg is singel byte and ax is 16 bit so word msg mean that ax shuld take this 1 byte as 16 bit(2 bytes)

Comment: and i try to print the resoltfor my first time so i copied the codefrom the internet , if i hed some mistake i will be very gratfull if you can put here the all code that work and explain me what i did rung

Comment: For using DOS interrupts for to write a string to the standard output of DOS, we need a 16 bit linker for to get a 16 bit executable. [link]http://download.microsoft.com/download/vc15/Update/1/WIN98/EN-US/Lnk563.exe

Answer (score 0):

Fixing those specific error messages will not give you the result you want.

When you are instructing the computer to XOR a value stored in AX, it will only apply to the 16 bits currently stored in AX. The assembler has no understanding that you are storing a string at the address of [msg].

You need to be iterating through the data referred to by [msg], XOR-ing each byte as long as it doesn't have a value of 0 (null terminated string).

[From StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592115/iterate-through-memory-editing-each-byte): The first answer shows how the looping could work, but does not deal with saving the result.

Pseudo-code:

```
Get a pointer to the start of the message.
Start loop.
  - Exit loop if referenced byte is 0.
  - XOR the byte referenced by the pointer.
  - Increment the pointer.
End loop.
```

Have a look at [Using Square Brackets To Reference Memory in ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291915/mov-ax-bx-vs-mov-ax-bx).

----------------- EDIT ---------------

To get single character functionality out of your code, try removing the square brackets as they de-reference the values stored in the register or at the location of the identifier. Also, do one byte at a time as your string is terminated with a single null byte.

You will need to generate an MS-DOS .EXE or .COM file if you want INT 21h functions to generate output.

```
encript_lbl:
mov al,msg
xor al,my_xor
mov msg,al
jmp print_lbl
```

[Details on the XOR instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_330.html)

Comment: Why i have to use a loop? i want to make only the first word jibrish and want to do it by xor why its wont work?

Comment: @h_meir Your question described that you wanted to encrypt the string. If you fixed your code so that "my_xor" was defined as a word, only the first two characters of the string would be modified.

Comment: What if i will use instead of ax rax? and also its fine by me to change only the first 2 char becoas than i can do a loop and the same for all the string ,my problem is that i cant do even this 2 becoas i cant put this varible inside ax without getting an error...